# Select2 with ajax remote data options component in Vuejs

Tags: arrays, ajax, vuejs2, jquery-select2

I wanna to use select2 with ajax remote data options in Vuejs 2.x. In [vuejs.org website](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html) located a sample for select2 component that work as static, but I need to select2 with [this specific](https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax) for my project. How to convert [JSFIDDLE Example](https://jsfiddle.net/d131Lebj/192/) to select2 that call an API with keyboard type.

In jQuery Select2 use this code for ajax call:

```
$('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
    ajax: {
      url: 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories',
      dataType: 'json'
      // Additional AJAX parameters go here; see the end of this chapter for the full code of this example
    }
});
```

Comment: What have you tried?  All you need to do is fire an ajax request in the `mounted` hook of the Vue instance and then pass the returned data to the component through `props` as the `options` prop in that fiddle.

Comment: @lamelemon thanks, please change sample code. I don't know to do

Answer (score 1):

Here is component that is working for me. Reference to their select2
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html

The gotcha for me was using `change.select2` instead of triggering `change` event in the watch.  `change` event causes infinite loop.

Your callback/ajax URL will need to return data with at least .id and .text properties.  See this URL for proper format https://select2.org/data-sources/formats

```
 <select2 v-model="member" name="member" callback="/res/member/select2.php" placeholder="Type a name"></select2>

Vue.component('select2', {
  props: ['name', 'value', 'required', 'callback', 'placeholder'],
  template: '<select :name="name" v-bind:class="{required: required}" class="vue-select2"></select>',
  watch : {
    value : function(value) {
      $(this.$el).empty().append('<option value="' + value.id + '">' + value.text +'</option>').trigger('change.select2');
    }
  },
  mounted:  function() {
    var that = this;
    var options = {
      width: '100%',
      placeholder: this.placeholder,
      allowClear: true,
      ajax: {
        url: this.callback,
        dataType: 'json'
      }
    };
    $(this.$el).select2(options);
    $(this.$el).on('change', function() {
      var item = $(this).select2('data')[0];
      that.$emit('input', item);
     
    });
  }
});
```